# Change color from my CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: java, android, colors

I am trying to do a CollapsingToolbar animation based in Material Design rules. Everything works well but a thing that is breaking down my mind. I am trying to change the color of my Collapsed tool bar when scroll my recycler view, but the transparent color that I get is allways the same...

Here is my xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@color/gps_friends_green_main"
            app:contentScrim="@color/gps_friends_green_main"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgHeader"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBarDetalleContacto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/MyNavigationDrawerTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And here is my Java's code

```
int mutedColor = R.color.gps_friends_green_main;

    Palette.generateAsync(bitmap,
                    new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                            Palette.Swatch vibrant =
                                    palette.getVibrantSwatch();

                            if (vibrant != null) {
                                // If we have a vibrant color
                                // update the title TextView
                                collapseToolbar.setBackgroundColor(mutedColor);
                                //  mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);
                                collapseToolbar.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getDarkMutedColor(R.color.gps_friends_green_main));
                                collapseToolbar.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(R.color.gps_friends_green_main));

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Where gps_friend_main_color is `<color name="gps_friends_green_main">#1abc9c</color>`

This is the result of my collapsed toolbar:

[image]

I want to change this dark blue color but I don't find the way to do that. I am a bit desperate but hope to find the answer here.
Thank  you.

Answer (score 5):

Your code to change the color is correct.
You just have to remove the

app:contentScrim="@color/gps_friends_green_main"

in your "android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout", and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your AppBarLayout: 
android:background="@android:color/transparent" // use any color here

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" //use any color here
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```